# UIButton click sender always go to selected option

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have a UIButton click sender as below:-

```
-(IBAction)clipButtonClick:(UIButton *)sender
{
    sender.selected  = ! sender.selected;

    if (sender.selected)
    {
        [btnClipCategory setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imgClip_HL"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

        NSMutableArray* indexArray = [NSMutableArray array];
        for (NSInteger i = 0; i < self.arySubCategory.count; i++)
        {
            [aryCheckCategoryList replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:@"YES"];
            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
            [indexArray addObject:indexPath];

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self.rightTableView reloadData];
            });

        }

    }
    else
    {
        [btnClipCategory setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imgClip"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        NSMutableArray* indexArray = [NSMutableArray array];
        for (NSInteger i = 0; i < self.arySubCategory.count; i++)
        {
            [aryCheckCategoryList replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:@"NO"];
            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
            [indexArray addObject:indexPath];



            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self.rightTableView reloadData];

            });

        }

    }
}
```

When I clicked on the button, sender will always hit on selected option.

If i change the sender to code to sample code as below, my apps will working properly as expected. Any idea? Please help. Thank you.

```
-(IBAction)clipButtonClick:(UIButton *)sender
{
    sender.selected  = ! sender.selected;

    if (sender.selected)
    {
        [btnClipCategory setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imgClip_HL"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        NSLog(@"Selected. Will Hit here");

    }
    else
    {
        [btnClipCategory setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imgClip"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        NSLog(@"Non Selected. Will Hit here");

    }
}
```

**Edited**
I put my button under willDisplayHeaderView.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayHeaderView:(UIView *)view forSection:(NSInteger)section{

    UITableViewHeaderFooterView *header = (UITableViewHeaderFooterView *)view;

    btnClipCategory = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [btnClipCategory setFrame:CGRectMake(header.frame.size.width - 45, header.frame.size.height * 0.2, ScreenW * 0.1, ScreenW * 0.1)];

    [btnClipCategory addTarget:self action:@selector(clipButtonClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [header addSubview:btnClipCategory];

}
```

Comment: Is `sender` view located somewhere inside the cells of `rightTableView`?

Comment: Hi @EgorKomarov, I put it under willDisplayHeaderView. You may refer to edited code as above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `[self.rightTableView reloadData]`, all the content of the table view including sections headers gets reloaded, and `tableView:willDisplayHeaderView:forSection:` gets called for each visible section header. So your `bntClipCategory` gets recreated with default value of `isSelected` each time click action fires.
You don't reload `rightTableView` in your working code sample, that's why it works.

You should reconsider you approach. One of the options is to save `isSelected` state of buttons for each section in array and update `btnClipCategory.isSelected` accordingly before adding it to header view.

Comment: Hi @Egor Komarov, thanks for your explaination, mind to share some sample code here? Your help is appreciated!